# angular is not defined In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and currently, I am doing controllers in AngularJS, but I don't know I got an error **`angular is not defined`** Line number 21 if someone knows the issue inform me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myLangApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.2/angular.min.js" integrity="sha512-7oYXeK0OxTFxndh0erL8FsjGvrl2VMDor6fVqzlLGfwOQQqTbYsGPv4ZZ15QHfSk80doyaM0ZJdvkyDcVO7KFA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="language">
            Select your favorite language:
            <button ng-click="selectLanguage('PHP')">PHP</button>
            <button ng-click="selectLanguage('javascript')">javascript</button>
            <button ng-click="selectLanguage('cpp')">cpp</button>
            <button ng-click="selectLanguage('java')">java</button>

            <p>You have selected: {{ myFavLang }}</p>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('myLangApp', []);
            app.controller('language',($scope)=>{
                $scope.myFavLang = 'None';
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MrJami Do you mean Where I import angular js?

Comment: use this reference for the head script `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add simple script to load the angular

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.2/angular.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: thank you for your valuable time now that works fine thank you again and have a good day.